# Put panel and text box in the same frame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, jtextarea

How do i put Jlabel and Jtext in the same frame?

if i add the text last, then only the text are showen, thes is my code:

```
public MatrixFrame(String framname, int width, int height) {

    width =7;
    height = 6;
    JFrame fram = new JFrame(framname);
    fram.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    fram.setSize(500,500);

    JTextArea text = new JTextArea("Here come Text");

    valMatrixPanel = new ValMatrixPanel(height,width,Color.GRAY, Color.black);

    JPanel pan = valMatrixPanel.getPan();       // pan is 6*7 panels lock the picture

    fram.add(pan);
    fram.add(text);
    fram.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this 
you will have to add a import for grid layout 
check that 
all you need to do is add a grid layout because the textbox overlaps the panel.
so add the line

**fame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));**

```
 JPanel pan = valMatrixPanel.getPan();       // pan is 6*7 panels lock the picture


    fame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));

    fram.add(pan);
    fram.add(text);
    fram.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

The key to solving this is your understanding how to use layout managers, because this is how Swing decides where to put what and how to size things. First off for a quick easy fix, put all your components into a JPanel, which uses a FlowLayout by default, and then add the JPanel to your JFrame. **Don't** set the JPanel's or the JFrame's size, **do** call `pack()` on the JFrame after adding everything and then finally call `setVisible(true)`.

The better long term answer: read the layout manager tutorials which you can find, among the other Swing tutorials: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info).

Answer (score 0):

use BorderLayout in fram.add()

like this

```
public MatrixFrame(String framname, int width, int height) {
width =7;
height = 6;
JFrame fram = new JFrame(framname);
fram.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
fram.setSize(500,500);

JTextArea text = new JTextArea("Here come Text");

valMatrixPanel = new ValMatrixPanel(height,width,Color.GRAY, Color.black);

JPanel pan = valMatrixPanel.getPan();       // pan is 6*7 panels lock the picture

fram.add(pan,BorderLayout.WEST);
fram.add(text,BorderLayout.NORTH);
fram.setVisible(true);
```

}